# How to apply weights from function svydesign into function coxph?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

How to use `coxph` to embed weights?

In the following codes, I wish I could use `coxph` to produce the same output as `svycoxph`.

Thank you!

Data

```
demo <- structure(list(SEP = c(142L, 112L, 104L, 119L, 102L, NA, 125L, 
 110L, 112L, 127L, 115L, 122L, NA, 95L, 137L, 124L, NA, 147L, 
 113L, 130L, 113L, 113L, 116L, NA, 114L, 128L, 108L, 115L, NA, 
 NA, 126L, 117L, 152L, 122L, 123L, 104L, 120L, 118L, NA, 111L, 
 137L, 96L, 141L, NA, 112L, NA, 141L, 124L, 131L, NA, 129L, 128L, 
 107L, 127L, 114L, 111L, 133L, 129L, NA, 112L, 114L, NA, NA, 118L, 
 115L, NA, 108L, 139L, 110L, 107L, 122L, 120L, 139L, 140L, 103L, 
 NA, 95L, 120L, 139L, 124L, 130L, 133L, 114L, 104L, 125L, 117L, 
 122L, 100L, 107L, 130L, 128L, 167L, 130L, 132L, 112L, NA, NA, 
 NA, 111L, 129L, 119L, 144L, NA, 118L, 125L, 115L, 123L, 120L, 
 120L, 115L, 123L, 117L, NA, NA, 102L, 108L, 109L, 107L, 146L, 
 126L, 143L, 126L, 105L, NA, 145L, 140L, 118L, NA, 112L, 124L, 
 114L, 112L, 109L, 130L, 102L, 128L, 138L, 139L, 108L, 111L, 127L, 
 113L, 146L, 131L, 129L, 133L, 102L, 135L, 100L, 133L, 117L, 101L, 
 NA, 123L, 134L, 85L, NA, 123L, 88L, 109L, 145L, 136L, 126L, 111L, 
 106L, 111L, NA, 114L, 124L, 119L, 144L, NA, 139L, 148L, 133L, 
 NA, 82L, NA, 97L, 132L, 108L, NA, NA, 115L, 127L, 119L, 144L, 
 149L, 138L, 113L, 124L, 109L, 139L, NA, 139L, 144L, 102L, 129L, 
 139L, 173L, 127L, NA, 138L, 205L, 124L, 125L, 123L, 126L, 115L, 
 160L, 128L, 113L, 130L, 108L, NA, 133L, NA, 124L, 108L, NA, 114L, 
 103L, NA, 122L, 112L, NA, 114L, 102L, 127L, 103L, 149L, 125L, 
 138L, 145L, 127L, 114L, 134L, 112L, 127L, NA, 124L, 101L, 98L, 
 150L, NA, 128L, 159L, 93L, NA, 132L, 107L, NA, 113L, 104L, 139L, 
 110L, 119L, NA, 127L, NA, 135L, NA, NA, 153L, 94L, 128L, 130L, 
 152L, 114L, 114L, NA, 123L, NA, 165L, 108L, 132L, 120L, 90L, 
 101L, 108L, 96L, 94L, 119L, 143L, 120L, 142L, 136L, NA, 100L, 
 121L, 117L, 119L, 129L, 116L, 129L, 123L, 126L, NA, 145L, 114L
), D_CVD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L
), syear = c(28.75, 28.666666667, 28.583333333, 7.8333333333, 
 26.166666667, 30.416666667, 27, 27, 27, 28.083333333, 17.333333333, 
 25.75, 28.666666667, 21.75, 30.25, 21.833333333, 1.4166666667, 
 20.666666667, 12.333333333, 30.916666667, 26.75, 30.166666667, 
 25.25, 27.333333333, 14.666666667, 12.25, 28.75, 7.9166666667, 
 30.916666667, 0.1666666667, 26.916666667, 29.583333333, 26.916666667, 
 26.416666667, 5.9166666667, 29.333333333, 29.75, 25.5, 22.75, 
 31, 3.5833333333, 5.8333333333, 26.666666667, 8.8333333333, 25.166666667, 
 24.583333333, 29.833333333, 0.8333333333, 18.083333333, 30.083333333, 
 29.833333333, 28.416666667, 26, 30.666666667, 16, 30.166666667, 
 27.083333333, 15.583333333, 16.833333333, 30.333333333, 4.5, 
 28.833333333, 28.416666667, 10.666666667, 28, 14.583333333, 27.333333333, 
 28.166666667, 6.3333333333, 26.25, 27, 26.916666667, 30.916666667, 
 14.25, 13.75, 28.333333333, 1.1666666667, 26.333333333, 30.083333333, 
 11.583333333, 15.666666667, 27.166666667, 15.916666667, 26.25, 
 25.75, 7.8333333333, 12.083333333, 2.5, 25.75, 14.916666667, 
 10.333333333, 25.75, 27.833333333, 25.583333333, 0.9166666667, 
 2.25, 22, 7.0833333333, 26.416666667, 30.75, 29.5, 28.583333333, 
 4.8333333333, 27.333333333, 15.916666667, 25.5, 14.166666667, 
 13.833333333, 19.166666667, 27, 27, 3.4166666667, 26.5, 19.25, 
 30.166666667, 18.583333333, 28.416666667, 29.25, 29.75, 27.083333333, 
 29.166666667, 2.3333333333, 18.583333333, 1, 13.916666667, 15.166666667, 
 30.833333333, 27.333333333, 26.666666667, 6.75, 22.333333333, 
 11.583333333, 27.583333333, 14.083333333, 30.916666667, 27.166666667, 
 27.916666667, 29.166666667, 30.666666667, 29.166666667, 5.6666666667, 
 26.25, 27.833333333, 29.416666667, 26.583333333, 26.75, 13.666666667, 
 22.416666667, 26.666666667, 25.583333333, 25.416666667, 29.5, 
 27.333333333, 27, 26.666666667, 26.5, 1, 24.333333333, 20, 28.75, 
 8.75, 13.916666667, 25.916666667, 27.333333333, 26.75, 25.75, 
 0.9166666667, 26, 13, 30.833333333, 4.5, 2.5833333333, 26, 18.083333333, 
 30.333333333, 14.583333333, 30.416666667, 14.833333333, 30.583333333, 
 6.6666666667, 29.333333333, 0.1666666667, 8.4166666667, 24.833333333, 
 19.583333333, 29.083333333, 25.833333333, 27.083333333, 28.25, 
 2.0833333333, 14.5, 26.583333333, 28, 19.583333333, 1.5, 25.833333333, 
 31, 3.6666666667, 26.333333333, 7.9166666667, 28, 26.25, 28, 
 27.583333333, 29.916666667, 30.25, 4.9166666667, 25.333333333, 
 25.416666667, 28.916666667, 28.083333333, 26.166666667, 11.5, 
 11.083333333, 23.916666667, 23.833333333, 27.166666667, 28.333333333, 
 27.416666667, 28.5, 2.0833333333, 30.833333333, 17.166666667, 
 11.75, 25.25, 7.5833333333, 30.333333333, 11.666666667, 18.666666667, 
 27.25, 14.583333333, 27.833333333, 29.75, 25.166666667, 26, 29.5, 
 20.25, 3.1666666667, 27, 1.1666666667, 25.75, 22.666666667, 12.75, 
 7.0833333333, 26.833333333, 23.083333333, 18.833333333, 27, 8.1666666667, 
 23.5, 28.5, 8.75, 9.75, 25.416666667, 11.083333333, 7.4166666667, 
 25.833333333, 26.5, 28.333333333, 28.5, 14.583333333, 19.833333333, 
 27.666666667, 0.0833333333, 30.25, 28.916666667, 28, 20.583333333, 
 26.333333333, 22.416666667, 6.5833333333, 30.083333333, 14.166666667, 
 26.583333333, 12.083333333, 26.25, 25.75, 26.666666667, 2.5, 
 26.333333333, 30.75, 25.666666667, 30.25, 9.8333333333, 30.25, 
 28.333333333, 28.333333333, 29.166666667, 5.75, 29.833333333, 
 25.666666667, 7.3333333333, 6.3333333333, 28.083333333, 31, 30.833333333, 
 28.083333333, 26.416666667, 19.25, 4.6666666667), SDPSTRA6 = c(33L, 
23L, 23L, 34L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 17L, 31L, 3L, 47L, 41L, 31L, 33L, 
1L, 29L, 40L, 19L, 8L, 14L, 42L, 30L, 27L, 21L, 44L, 32L, 31L, 
25L, 49L, 28L, 31L, 8L, 7L, 32L, 27L, 17L, 40L, 13L, 8L, 12L, 
10L, 24L, 14L, 14L, 45L, 19L, 7L, 3L, 19L, 24L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 
17L, 30L, 31L, 30L, 49L, 34L, 43L, 31L, 2L, 8L, 33L, 14L, 23L, 
46L, 22L, 26L, 2L, 36L, 49L, 21L, 38L, 2L, 22L, 20L, 9L, 18L, 
12L, 17L, 40L, 20L, 8L, 13L, 12L, 2L, 38L, 36L, 32L, 41L, 19L, 
28L, 18L, 6L, 3L, 13L, 38L, 21L, 43L, 27L, 7L, 22L, 26L, 25L, 
23L, 28L, 12L, 31L, 1L, 16L, 22L, 23L, 9L, 36L, 43L, 17L, 40L, 
31L, 35L, 27L, 8L, 4L, 28L, 39L, 49L, 23L, 45L, 8L, 26L, 17L, 
22L, 21L, 3L, 18L, 43L, 35L, 4L, 32L, 49L, 26L, 4L, 44L, 34L, 
30L, 5L, 33L, 30L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 7L, 34L, 39L, 2L, 20L, 
24L, 31L, 5L, 33L, 47L, 21L, 15L, 8L, 40L, 47L, 30L, 21L, 32L, 
20L, 47L, 34L, 34L, 6L, 22L, 17L, 48L, 5L, 46L, 20L, 3L, 16L, 
34L, 32L, 9L, 31L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 32L, 19L, 20L, 8L, 41L, 12L, 
11L, 47L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 43L, 48L, 25L, 34L, 30L, 27L, 16L, 33L, 
33L, 11L, 29L, 19L, 12L, 33L, 31L, 26L, 21L, 6L, 22L, 3L, 7L, 
43L, 29L, 37L, 34L, 12L, 18L, 5L, 7L, 19L, 18L, 29L, 49L, 45L, 
8L, 14L, 7L, 6L, 13L, 8L, 15L, 27L, 42L, 31L, 18L, 4L, 15L, 2L, 
6L, 26L, 48L, 27L, 45L, 39L, 47L, 38L, 10L, 27L, 7L, 8L, 34L, 
31L, 9L, 29L, 44L, 47L, 20L, 28L, 6L, 24L, 37L, 12L, 22L, 22L, 
41L, 15L, 22L, 20L, 21L, 9L, 1L, 49L, 11L, 10L, 26L, 20L, 41L, 
39L, 8L, 40L, 1L, 3L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 38L, 10L, 20L), SDPPSU6 = c(1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), WTPFEX6 = c(70305.12, 
26679.42, 2392.94, 1, 20418.58, 34632.97, 9170.88, 9065.17, 1898.6, 
3385.47, 48497.36, 1071.86, 71804, 1836.87, 20281.17, 4292.7, 
1, 8235.62, 8576.61, 2568.94, 10018.47, 13817.29, 1496.91, 9961.41, 
21211.54, 26056.15, 2182.63, 1388.16, 5133.71, 1, 1532.26, 2534.9, 
3903.85, 4166.76, 11640.77, 36030.38, 15193.64, 3242.98, 2588.14, 
30773, 2664.96, 1, 10534.91, 1511.47, 448.77, 1, 16470.85, 1, 
2350.66, 1, 18470.06, 13400.55, 3136.18, 45311.92, 8305.63, 18901.18, 
1898.6, 1683.18, 1, 1820.01, 561.36, 1, 1, 7500.18, 27127.77, 
1, 2661.3, 2227.7, 2435.81, 32110.52, 61257.88, 2594.27, 1550.47, 
21145.56, 2631.77, 1, 5569.31, 3894.58, 3689.18, 1559.86, 9186.91, 
8428.62, 10957.64, 3894.58, 27327.4, 1220.33, 35432.29, 11618.4, 
10799.48, 8662.42, 17790.83, 1438.94, 59012.42, 1246.2, 2600.09, 
1, 3274.35, 5781.14, 10799.48, 4716.12, 9442.2, 19845.66, 1, 
2742.66, 1466.43, 858.56, 15748.05, 399.24, 2643.2, 19468.16, 
38622.86, 1629.12, 1, 1, 3077.67, 2473.32, 1814.24, 9953.44, 
1401.84, 4726.59, 3611.62, 4362.71, 15016.25, 1, 544.53, 511.16, 
2132.95, 2993.76, 3533.34, 7500.18, 2990.94, 8772.44, 3704.02, 
24069.73, 4397.87, 1682.75, 36060.87, 3941.6, 3630.22, 7126.87, 
1947.65, 1326.43, 54646.15, 1275.45, 22828.25, 19627.39, 23796.23, 
1, 4494, 1068.12, 1589.53, 1915.72, 1, 39353.42, 22828.25, 1122.5, 
13147.49, 5342.93, 2408.39, 4592.06, 11022.59, 31529.06, 37841.46, 
24883.34, 33771.31, 2883.48, 12193.27, 49085.22, 1390.43, 20740.41, 
4722.67, 1, 2448.05, 11763.34, 1583.02, 1, 5808.52, 1, 2104.03, 
11771.04, 1749.21, 1, 5626.76, 8160.31, 6857.48, 3351.51, 4505.82, 
4411.05, 19063.88, 23577.03, 13043.05, 44167.93, 10635.15, 3832.6, 
2855.58, 1438.94, 3690.31, 5445.54, 1906.9, 3648.03, 13601.59, 
3812.9, 2263.26, 30582.5, 2801.9, 1915.69, 917.02, 14590.25, 
24765.25, 59661.84, 2236.43, 3424.55, 15998.15, 6982.24, 1, 951.83, 
1, 4200.6, 5177.99, 7718.35, 8319.23, 7082.91, 1, 1824.88, 54463.42, 
25085.12, 7746.23, 4491.25, 5856.82, 5114.27, 9043.98, 2278.74, 
49639.31, 3422.93, 6296.11, 1334.39, 589.08, 2134.13, 30255.34, 
1, 4698.28, 23572.91, 8520.58, 10193.14, 1, 14869.29, 4843.95, 
21110.42, 1, 18366.32, 23390.25, 1, 3486.36, 1436.43, 443.71, 
563.86, 2280.91, 1, 22098.83, 19845.66, 10745.24, 1, 1, 1959.98, 
3617.72, 2471.76, 41588.8, 1877.66, 45992.91, 2197.45, 1, 24780.76, 
1, 35139.21, 1, 4029.27, 492.95, 3242.55, 10250.8, 29930.07, 
7742.58, 48058.22, 25040.37, 4795.47, 13525.29, 4418.72, 3731.79, 
7691.44, 367.45, 2207.73, 31226.75, 2276.24, 10989.21, 3385.47, 
23638.87, 4397.87, 5682.27, 2869, 1, 3868.25)), row.names = c(3015L, 
8586L, 8677L, 11466L, 9224L, 8701L, 15210L, 11787L, 4196L, 9629L, 
12854L, 13543L, 8607L, 10722L, 7847L, 9800L, 19320L, 11658L, 
19045L, 1907L, 12858L, 14351L, 1425L, 11314L, 15872L, 19384L, 
47L, 16412L, 2951L, 17309L, 10719L, 338L, 18070L, 7007L, 15689L, 
7960L, 10131L, 11287L, 13905L, 8726L, 16943L, 18068L, 6271L, 
12688L, 15704L, 12533L, 4918L, 16987L, 14398L, 63L, 9846L, 14585L, 
6852L, 795L, 17084L, 4777L, 4475L, 10430L, 11073L, 419L, 13784L, 
4971L, 166L, 14622L, 1053L, 10786L, 7006L, 3271L, 6605L, 3389L, 
9249L, 6162L, 5077L, 9030L, 4254L, 2868L, 16125L, 9704L, 8603L, 
12914L, 18659L, 6359L, 19103L, 6346L, 8872L, 16100L, 2322L, 17860L, 
6095L, 15568L, 19431L, 4113L, 3682L, 1383L, 17507L, 16967L, 9388L, 
18137L, 6820L, 2871L, 528L, 5998L, 19079L, 7009L, 6366L, 6465L, 
13991L, 14350L, 17575L, 1221L, 10818L, 14928L, 10728L, 11507L, 
5505L, 14502L, 753L, 10189L, 1890L, 1217L, 9825L, 17021L, 13383L, 
18730L, 19022L, 14665L, 2911L, 6481L, 1842L, 17006L, 13185L, 
13531L, 3780L, 4203L, 160L, 14290L, 9972L, 8023L, 5368L, 11690L, 
6677L, 7168L, 717L, 5881L, 7323L, 11406L, 12297L, 14789L, 6488L, 
1207L, 1184L, 5252L, 4137L, 3571L, 9602L, 10987L, 15538L, 845L, 
14941L, 4719L, 15463L, 16384L, 6756L, 11407L, 4259L, 10625L, 
13911L, 4119L, 15984L, 2508L, 16942L, 16534L, 1336L, 19111L, 
8313L, 14066L, 10201L, 15739L, 4734L, 19185L, 5513L, 18325L, 
17606L, 11306L, 11374L, 2369L, 3426L, 3712L, 7965L, 11576L, 13642L, 
12913L, 16004L, 9428L, 17179L, 3472L, 5339L, 17733L, 13554L, 
12906L, 15944L, 3730L, 1838L, 1319L, 11489L, 2444L, 17064L, 4070L, 
11754L, 136L, 11430L, 11310L, 19144L, 13038L, 16795L, 14323L, 
1584L, 82L, 10504L, 4583L, 14630L, 11007L, 16316L, 17896L, 3745L, 
8245L, 8704L, 2631L, 19203L, 10628L, 18407L, 7553L, 5562L, 3844L, 
12800L, 2205L, 12532L, 18704L, 9093L, 15312L, 9988L, 13853L, 
18211L, 16439L, 11880L, 18987L, 16152L, 12548L, 14740L, 15928L, 
2358L, 16281L, 16657L, 6778L, 18241L, 16539L, 1410L, 3715L, 5323L, 
8688L, 16090L, 16232L, 11252L, 12299L, 10850L, 5372L, 4006L, 
12204L, 3601L, 13315L, 18820L, 10309L, 18283L, 1455L, 9905L, 
1313L, 19513L, 1566L, 13958L, 14219L, 5849L, 1087L, 10136L, 16983L, 
14660L, 240L, 2989L, 8617L, 13102L, 896L, 9243L, 17620L, 18866L, 
9520L, 804L, 249L, 9983L, 1555L, 16694L, 12630L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code

```
library(survey)
demoDesign <- svydesign(data = demo, strata = ~SDPSTRA6, id = ~SDPPSU6, nest = TRUE, weights = ~WTPFEX6)
svycoxph(Surv(syear,D_CVD) ~ SEP, design=demoDesign)

library(survival)
coxph(Surv(syear,D_CVD) ~ SEP, data=demo)
```

Comment: Are you having any issues with `svycoxph(Surv(syear,D_CVD) ~ SEP, design=demoDesign)`?

Comment: I was following the flow at https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/tutorials/part-2-single-episode-cox-regression-model-time-invariant-predictors, and they used ```coxph``` in there. With the ```svycoxph```, I cannot move further following that webpage. That's why I wondered if I could use ```coxph``` to replace my ```svycoxph```.

Comment: Gotcha - There is also another package `coxphw` [(see here)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxphw/vignettes/jss_2018_example_code.html) that may be of interest. Good luck!

Comment: I reworded my question a bit. Please see if the current version makes more sense. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad. If the question were narrowed down to construction residuals in output from `svycoxph` it might be a suitable question, but as it stands it's asking us to replicate an entire tutorial done with `coxph` but using `svycoxph` and it's not even describing the research question or sampling strategy.

Comment: I also think you may not have done much searching. It didn't take very long to find this tutorial: "Cox Proportional Hazards Model Part 2 - Model Checking" that did the work of model checking with svycoxph output: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/316608_ce1f6a723cff4b7d8ec65676779b12c6.html . The google search strategy was `assessing proportionality assumptions in weighted  "svycoxph"`

Comment: @IRTFM Thank you for the resources. I will take a look at it. The mentioned website was just one of the reasons. There are other functions that I encountered that had difficulties working with ```svycoxph```, which I cannot recall them at this moment. I was unhappy with ```svycoxph``` for quite some time and finally wanted to try to break up with it, and see if I could use ```coxph``` instead. Hence this question.

Comment: @IRTFM If using ```coxph``` to replace ```svycoxph``` is hardly doable in this case, then I have to stick with ```svycoxph```. Since I don't have much experience with ```coxph```, and searching on google did not give me an answer, I think it would be helpful to get some information from here. If an experienced user of ```coxph``` told me "No, it can't", then I will "happily" use the old function ```svycoxph```.

Comment: One of my criticisms is the complete lack of clarity about exactly what "difficulties working with svycoxph" actually means. If it means "examining various residuals" that the offered external resource would seem to fit the bill. If I'm correct, then you should apply that code and approach to your data and post an answer.

Comment: No it is not. I overcame those difficulties previously that’s why I can’t recall them. I think the question itself ask clearly if one function could be used to replace another function. I would appreciate if anyone could share some info on it if any. Thanks for your input!